# How to make a image fade out to both sides

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, adobe-fireworks

I want to use an image in different screen resolutions with fading and the same background color. In a website, the image will not scale, but the background will. Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using a transparent gradient mask.

This tutorial is quite similar, just use your background color in a separate layer underneath: http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/photoshop/transparent/gradient.html

More details on masks: http://www.creativemac.com/2003/07_jul/tutorials/psgradient030723.htm and http://wegraphics.net/blog/tutorials/photoshop/photoshop-for-beginners-understanding-layer-mask/

Comment: The question is about web graphics with a variable width. If the OP takes the concepts in this answer (transparency and layers) and then outputs each layer with alpha channel (PNG format) and then layers them in place on the web page, perhaps the OP will have the desired result.